# How to run a script at a specific time, like every Saturday?

Tags: perl, unix, cron, scheduled-tasks

Under unix system ..

I want to run a perl script A.pl in every Saturday. I tried the code below, it works. But I am wondering does there exists any other code can work but does not keep checking the time in a busy loop?

```
while(1)
{
        @Time = localtime();
        if( $Time[6] eq "6" )
        {
                `perl A.pl`;
        }
}
```

Comment: On which OS are you? Windows? Linux? Mac? (...)

Comment: Do you really want to run this repeatedly, with no interval between runs?

Comment: @WilliamPursell No , so I come here for help ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in [crontab](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?crontab) as follows:

```
0 0 * * 6 /path/to/perl A.pl
```

This is, of course, assuming you're on Unix. I have no clue about Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Under Unix, running programs periodically is the job of `cron`. Users can edit their jobs into the *crontab* using the `crontab -e` command (set your `EDITOR` environment variable to your favorite editor).

The format of the crontab is described in *crontab(5)* which you read with

```
 man 5 crontab
```

The most common gotcha for new cron users is that cron jobs are run with a minimal environment; not even `PATH` is exported so you *have* to set `PATH` in your program.

So where does your program's output go? Any output on *stdout* or *stderr* will be mailed to your account. If you want it somewhere else, your crontab line must redirect the output, e.g. with a crontab entry like this (note: sh syntax, not csh syntax!):

```
# Quarter past 8 on Saturdays.
15 20 * * 6  /home/user/bin/A.pl >/home/user/A.stdout 2>/home/user/A.stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a unix/linux system you can put your A.pl script in the crontab.

Comment: How to put something in a crontab? What are the exact steps?

Comment: @hd1 I saw your answer! Don't discourage a new comer... I try to give him/her some clue how to write an acceptable answer...

Comment: type: crontab -e
then enter the following lines (as @Jens posted above):
0 0 * * 6 /path/to/perl A.pl

i.e.:
0 0 * * 6 /usr/bin/perl A.pl